# Simple yet efficient integer-to-object dictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, category

Sometimes I need an `NSDictionary`-like object that maps a few integers (non-negative) to objects. At first glance, `NSMutableArray` is great for this, provided that the indexes aren't too high so I came up with [a quick category to allow holes in an array](http://cutecoder.org/programming/behold-holy-array/):

```
@implementation NSArray (FoundationAdditions)

-(id) objectAtCheckedIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    if(index >= self.count) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        id result =  [self objectAtIndex:index];
        return result == [NSNull null] ? nil : result;
    }
}

@end


@implementation NSMutableArray (FoundationAdditions)

-(void) setObject:(id) object atCheckedIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    NSNull* null = [NSNull null];
    if (!object) {
        object = null;
    }

    NSUInteger count = self.count;
    if (index < count) {
        [self replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:object];
    } else {
        if (index > count) {
            NSUInteger delta = index - count;
            for (NSUInteger i=0; i<delta;i++) {
                [self addObject:null];
            }
        }
        [self addObject:object];
    }
}

@end
```

Is there a better/easier/simpler way to do this? Preferably using something that's pre-existing in the Cocoa stack. Yes I know STL has some pretty good containers in this area, but mixing-in C++ just for this is overkill.

Comment: Can you clarify what your motivation is?  Are you wanting to optimize for lookup speed, at the expense of memory usage?  Something else?

Comment: @nate Both lookup speed and saving some memory – without needing to store `NSNumber` objects as keys if I use `NSDictionary` for this use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write a custom class that uses an `NSMutableDictionary` internally, boxing the indexes into `NSNumber` keys.

Depending on your particular use case it’s probably going to be both faster and more memory efficient than stuffing the unused array items with `NSNull`. Boxing the integer indexes into `NSNumber` key objects sounds like a lot of work performance-wise, but since the implementation uses [tagged pointers](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in), it should be pretty fast.

For extra points you can implement the [object subscripting accessors](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) (`objectAtIndexedSubscript:` and `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:`) and enjoy simple access syntax (`foo[x]`).

Comment: Yep, you're right. I started this back in iOS 3 and tagged pointers just made this obsolete.